# Github Action : How to run workflow and deploy container instance with required tags policies

Tags: azure, dockerfile, containers, github-actions, policies

I have the following workflow:

```html
build-and-deploy:
        needs: [deploy_checks]
        environment: ${{ needs.deploy_checks.outputs.env_name }}
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        # checkout the repo
        - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
          uses: actions/checkout@main
          
        - name: 'Login via Azure CLI'
          uses: azure/login@v1
          with:
            creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
        
        - name: 'Build and push image'
          uses: azure/docker-login@v1
          with:
            login-server: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}
            username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
            password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
        - run: |
            docker build . -t ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/name_image:${{ github.sha }}
            docker push ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/name_image:${{ github.sha }}
        - name: 'Deploy to Azure Container Instances'
          uses: 'azure/aci-deploy@v1'
          with:
            resource-group: ${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}
            dns-name-label: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CONTAINER_DNS_NAME }}
            cpu: 1
            memory: 1 
            ports: port
            image: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/name_image:${{ github.sha }}
            registry-login-server: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}
            registry-username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
            registry-password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
            #environment-tag: ${{ secrets.ENVIRONMENT_SECRET }}
            #project-tag: ${{ secrets.PROJECT_SECRET }}
            name: container_name
            environment-variables: ENV=${{ env.ENV }} PROFILE=${{ env.PROFILE }}  
            secure-environment-variables: AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=${{ env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING }}
            location: location
```

After compliance policies update, my workflow "was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers:" require two tags : tag1 and tag2.
github action output in step 'build-and-deploy' :
**`Error: Resource '***' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers: '[***"policyAssignment":***"name":"Require XXX tag on resources"]`**

So I need to add tags to my container instance during creation.
How can that be achieved? How do you reference the tags inside "build-and-deploy"?